# Domain Driven Design - Entities VO's and Class Hierarchy

Tags: domain-driven-design, class-hierarchy

The shorter version of the Question: "Is it ok to have a superclass, with 2 subclasses, one is an entity the other is a Value Object?"

To longer version:
T have a **Team** superclass. The **Team** has the **Master**, **Helpers** and a **Code**.
Then i have the **DefaultTeam**, subclass of **Team**, which is an entity with an **unique **Code**** has its domain identity. 
Then i have the **ExecutionTeam**, its a subclass of **Team** and has an extra attribute **OriginalTeam**:

```
public abstract class Team{

    public string Code{ get; protected set; }

    public Worker Master{ get; protected set; }

    public IList<Worker > Helpers { get; protected set; }
    ...

}

public class DefaultTeam: Team
{
}

public class ExecutionTeam : Team
{

    public virtual string Code { get { return OriginalTeam.Code; } }

    public virtual DefaultTeam OriginalTeam { get; private set; }

   ...

 }
```

The **ExecutionTeam**, is the team that executes a **Task**. 
When a **Task** needs to be executed, we choose a **DefaultTeam** to execute it.
But we can change the **Helpers** from the **DefaultTeam** (the master never changes).

That team that executes the task, is a variation of the **DefaultTeam** (**OriginalTeam**), but with the **Helpers** that were chosen just for that Task.

The **ExecutionTeam** will have the **same code has the OriginalTeam**. So the **ExecutionTeam has no unique identity**.
If there are 10 executions of tasks by the same **DefaultTeam**, there will be 10 **ExecutionTeams** with the same code (with the same **OriginalTeam**). So **ExecutionTeam** is cannot be an Entity.

But having an Entity and a Value Object sharing the same superclass (both being Teams), is a bit strange. Maybe this domain model has something wrong.

Need opinions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like ExecutionTeam might be better modeled as an interface `ICanExecuteTasks`.  Would that work for you?  It would eliminate the issue you are struggling with..

As to your short question,  if the `ExecutionTeam` was indeed a derived class of `Team`, (inheriting from team and representing an "IsA" relatoonship, then the answer is No, they cannot be of different types because of course, every ExecutionTeam isA Team, thgere is only one thing, which is both a `Team` and an `ExecutionTeam` at the same time... It cannot be both an entity Type and a value type at the same time.

But the way you have designed the classes, as you have structured things, `ExcecutionTeam` is not a derived class, it is a property of the `DefaultTeam`.  This implies that they have a "HasA" relationship.  THis implies that they are different, co-existing objects, one of which can be an entity and one of which can be a value type.  But my gut tells me this is not an accurate mirror of your real domain model...

Comment: yes, i think we will have to review the domain model. The DedaultTeam, is useless, if the team helpers are variable, it makes no sense for them to be there, the team supervisor is the only relevant information in the default team... the only purpose for the default members is that our customer will use them more oftem with that team sueprvisor, than other members

Comment: ahhh well, continuous domain model review and modification, at each step reaching a deeper understanding of the domain, and making the corresponding changes in your technical design so that it aLso evolves to closer mirror that deeper understanding, is in fact a hallmark of DDD, and a good sign you are doing DDD correctly! –

Answer (score 0):

What is it that makes the DefaultTeam a Value Object rather than an Entity? Isn't a DefaultTeam also an entity?

That being said, here are some comments:

1. Why do you need a special class for DefaultTeam? Can't a DefaultTeam simply be an ExecutionTeam, with certain specified values?
2. A DefaultTeam should probably be an instance of a Team that is associated with an application domain. For example, you might have a particular team that is generally used to solve problems with Project XYZ.
3. Instead of listing "DefaultTeam" as a property of the ExecutionTeam, you should probably have a "PreviousTeam" as a property of both the Team and ExecutionTeam classes.
   This will be more generalizable, in case the team gets changed yet again.
4. Since Task is an important part of the domain and is assigned to a Team, it should probably be a property of Team.
5. "Helpers" doesn't seem an appropriate name for the team members. Why not just name them "Members" or "TeamMembers"?
6. "Master" is probably un-PC unless you are working in Dilbert land or dealing with a database :) You might want to change this to "Supervisor" or "Manager".
7. "Code" is probably a bad name in the context of your application, as it may easily be confused with programming code. You might want to use "Id" or "TeamId" instead.

Comment: Hi, as for the names its a rough translation from portuguese to english, the original names are more correct :).

Comment: "Why do you need a special class for DefaultTeam? Can't a DefaultTeam simply be an ExecutionTeam, with certain specified values?"
if i execute a Task t1 in a specific Date d1, with Team t1, then when i execute another task t2 in another date d2 and i want to use Team t1, but with different members, if i don't have the execution team concept, then when i change t1 members that change will reflect in the older task t1 execution, if i want to pay team t1 workers for the tasks they executed, then the members of the last definition of t1 will get all the money.

Comment: So execution team is like a snapshot of a default team with the chosen members, when they execute a task.

Comment: Ah, ok :) I didn't realize the program was written in Portuguese.